# Recover complex function from its imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The real part of $z=x+yi$ is given as $\Im f(z) = x^2-y_2+x$. Therefore I have
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
G_x = 2x+1 \\ 
G_y = -2y
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
G_{xx} = 2 \\ 
G_{yy} = -2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$G_{xx} + G_{yy} = 0$, therefore the function is harmonic.

Next step is
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
u_x = G_y = -2y \\ 
u_y = -G_x = -2x-1 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Then,
$$u=\int u_x\ dx=-2xy+h(y)+C$$
$$u_y = -2x-1$$
Therefore,
$$u = -2xy - 2x - 1$$
Finally,
$$f(z) = u+iv = -2xy-2x-1 + i(x^2-y^2+x) +C= -2xy - 2x-1 + x^2i+y^2i+xi +C= i(x^2-y^2+2xyi) + (-2x-1+xi) + C = iz^2 + (-2x-1+xi) + C$$
But this is a wrong answer. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u = -2xy - 2x - 1$ is wrong !

From $u=-2xy+h(y)+C$ we get

$u_y=-2x+h'(y)=-G_x=-2x-1$, hence $u=-2xy-y+c$.

Comment: Thanks, I just don't get why you put $h'(y)$ instead of -1